# values folder for multi-screen support

Tags: android, layout, margin, screen-resolution, dpi

by android doc  .... guide/practices/screens_support .....
[image]

i have values folder for margins in my app like below image

[image]

but only green ones are correct and red ones are not!

[image]

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple layout for support tablet,other screen sizes

```
layout-sw320dp // screen is greater than or equal to 320dp
layout-sw480dp // screen is greater than or equal to 480dp
layout-sw600dp //5 inch tablet
layout-sw720dp //10 inch tablet
```

Comment: should i create values-sw320dp & ... for those layouts?